# Joining two tables twice in MySQL. Possible or Not???

Tags: mysql, join

The table structures for the tables users,messages are like bellow,

```
Users - ID, Name

Messages - ID, Sender, Receiver, Message
```

I want to join two tables twice like joining the messages.sender with users.id and  messages.receiver with users.id.

Is it possible to get the result with **sender's id, sender's name, receiver's id, receiver's name, message...(etc)** in a single query???...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it by naming an inner join:

```
 select id, s.Name, r.Name from Messages
    inner join users as s on (message.sender = s.id)
    inner join users as r on (merssage.receiver = r.id)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can join the tables as many times as needed.

```
SELECT 
  sender.ID AS `sender_id`, 
  sender.Name AS `sender_name`, 
  receiver.ID AS `receiver_id`, 
  receiver.Name AS `receiver_name`, 
  Messages.Message
FROM
  Messages
INNER JOIN
  Users AS sender
ON
  sender.ID = Messages.Sender
INNER JOIN
  Users AS receiver
ON
  receiver.ID = Messages.Receiver
```